# Retrieving an XML value in Cake build?

Tags: cakebuild

Is there a simple way of retrieving an XML value from a file using the Cake build automation system?

I've been poking around the [Cake.Common.Xml namespace](http://cakebuild.net/api/cake.common.xml), but everything seems geared toward modifying (`XmlPoke`) or transforming (`XmlTransformation`) XML. The docs on those methods make them appear to be geared toward prepping XML for use in later build steps to consume, so they don't return anything.

Ideally, I would like to just go in to a `FilePath` object with an XPath query string and get the resulting value.

Specifically, I'm trying to extract values from a Xamarin.Android project's AndroidManifest.xml for use in naming the resulting APK from a Cake.Xamarin call, but it seems like this functionality should be at the Cake.Common.Xml level.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of [Cake v0.8.0](https://github.com/cake-build/cake/releases/tag/v0.8.0), there is now `XmlPeek` from the [`Cake.Common.Xml.XmlPeekAliases` namespace](http://cakebuild.net/api/cake.common.xml/a5620ad4). You pass it a `FilePath` instance and an XPath query (with optional settings for things like namespaces), and it will return a string.

For example, given some local XML file like this…

```
<some>
    <nested>
        <thing someattribute="attributevalue" />
        <otherthing>some text value</otherthing>
    </nested>
</some>
```

For example, to get an attribute's value…

```
var attributeValue = XmlPeek(File("example.xml"),
    "/some/nested/thing/@someattribute")
```

…will get you a string of `attributevalue`.

And to get a text nodes value…

```
var textNodeValue = XmlPeek(File("example.xml"),
    "/some/nested/otherthing/text()");
```

…will get you a string of `some text value`.

Answer (score 1):

As you are obviously aware (since you created it) there is an active Pull Request for Cake to add this functionality:

https://github.com/cake-build/cake/pull/641

Once ready, this Pull Request will be pulled into Cake, and the functionality will be available out of the box in Cake.

Comment: **NOTE:** This Pull Request has just been merged into the develop branch, and it should be available in the next release of Cake, which will be 0.8.0.

Comment: Get it while it is hot :-) https://www.nuget.org/packages/Cake/0.8.0 Version 0.8.0 of Cake, which includes the XmlPeek alias, has just been released.